# Postman dictionary for multiple variables.

Tags: loops, postman

On a POST request via Postman I pass the dealer id in the body of the request with the bearer token and run my test collection. Is there a way to set it as a variable and use a dealer id dictionary to loop through all of the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv as a source of those. See [THIS](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/) blog post.